# liferay like restfull api mobile

Tags: mobile, liferay

I have a app and I need develop a restfull api to be used for this app.
Is liferay a valid option to develop this (using the service builder and persistence layer of liferay) to expose my service api to be used for the app?

I have in mind the performance and availability to this services.

what another option (to develop the api rest) i should consider for this purpose

Thanks 
I expect for your replies.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay can act as a rest server by service buider (I'm not sure it will support any RESTful operation, but only GET/POST).
By this way you can inherit the interesting features provided such as:
- users, roles and groups
- ready scalable platform
- hibernate+ehcache already configured
Ecc... by the other hand, it will bring a great burden to you... so in my mind, if you are interested to other Liferay native features, then you can use it.

On contrary, there are other ligther frameworks for achieving your needs (just think to Spring MVC, it can implement any other restful method, like so PUT/DELETE... and it is more configurable)... so in this case it will ask you to do a bit more work by hand... but you will not "fight" with a complex platform if it is not necessary.

(In the first hypothesis, don't forget to give an eye to the "Liferay Mobile SDK")

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answer.

In fact, I am interested in use the features of liferay like users, groups, profiles, persistence layer and the web content to manager some resources in the app.
My question is thinking in the performance and scalability of the services layer for this app, if is factible use only liferay to expose all the service to the app need and if her performance will be appropriate.

regards.

Comment: Yes, if you properly cluster your Liferay installation, it will automatically scale (in terms of request processing, database cache, etc.). Put an eye to the "Liferay Mobile SDK": if I'm not in wrong it help to build native applications, providing an automatically wrapped access to service layer calls.